# append fold column to training data frame using splitTools

Tags: r

I am using this code and the package [splitTools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/splitTools/vignettes/splitTools.html):

```
library(splitTools)

set.seed(3451)
inds <- partition(iris$Sepal.Length, p = c(train = 0.8, test = 0.2))

train <- iris[inds$train,]
test <- iris[inds$test,]

folds <- create_folds(train$Sepal.Length, k = 5)
```

The returned object folds is a list of integers. Is it possible to append a column fold to the the data frame train containing the fold number (in this case 1,2,3,4 or 5)? Thanks.

PS:

Miserable attempt:

```
results <- NULL
index <- 1
for (fold in folds) {
    t <- train[-fold,]
    t$fold <- index
    index <- index + 1
    results <- rbind(results, t)
}

table(results$fold)
train <- results
head(train)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to transform the folds to dataframe and then create an index for rows and add the values as TRUE/FALSE according to the fold. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
#Bind
L <- lapply(folds, function(x) data.frame(val=x))
dffolds <- do.call(rbind,L)
dffolds$Fold <- gsub('\\..*','',rownames(dffolds))
rownames(dffolds)<-NULL
#Reshape
Folds <- dffolds %>% group_by(Fold) %>%
  mutate(V=T) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Fold,values_from=V,values_fill=F)
#Merge
train2 <- train %>%
  mutate(val=row_number()) %>%
  left_join(Folds) %>%
  select(-val)
```

Output (some rows and columns):

```
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species Fold1 Fold2 Fold3
1            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
2            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
3            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
4            5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
5            4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3     setosa  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
6            5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
7            4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1     setosa FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
8            5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2     setosa  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
9            4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1     setosa  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
10           4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1     setosa  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: thanks - I added a PS to my original question, which seems to work but is probably very clumsy

Comment: @cs0815 I saw it, it is also good, great job :)

Comment: Not sure why you end up with only 3 folds and it should also be in long format?

Comment: @cs0815 Please omit that, I ended up with 5 folds, but I did not include due to space :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in getting the indices of the "out-of-fold" partition per row, it is easier via `partition`. `create_folds` itself calls `partition`, so you don't lose any logic by doing so:

```
iris$fold <- partition(iris$Sepal.Length, p = rep(0.2, 5), split_into_list = FALSE)

# Gives
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species fold
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa    4
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa    2
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa    4
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa    5
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa    4
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa    3
>
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of splitTools and very grateful for hints how to improve the package :-).